# I didn't receive an email that the web apps site was launched

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, beta-phase, email-notification

We have a new site that's in beta now, the [Web applications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) proposal. I've been committed to it (for a while), but I didn't receive an email with info that is was created. I only found out by posts here on meta, and the Area 51 site. I was able to create an account and everything just fine though.

I don't know if I'm the only one or if others didn't receive the mail notification.

**Note:** I did receive other emails from Area 51.

**Update:**
I received the mail this night. I'm not sure how delayed it was, about one day I think. Reminds me of snail mail, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the email was sent to your address. Those emails shouldn't be any different from the others, so I'm not sure what happened but I'm marking this `status-norepro` for now.

Comment: Thanx. I got the mail though a bit late. Wondered if you had resent it before going here.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly *did* receive an email - so the system clearly works to some extent, at least.

Check your spam folders, perhaps?

Comment: It's not in a spam folder etc. It would also be strange why this email should be special when the others have passed through perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not verify your email address, you will not receive the notification email. But (assuming you committed) you should have access to the site. Try logging in using your OpenID.